Why increment counters by 1 in stream ciphers?
What is the security rationale behind incrementing by 1 in stream ciphers like ChaCha20Poly1305—which often only changes one or two bits and is very weak and predictible—versus other methods like incrementing by a pre-agreed odd number at a pre-agreed initial counter value? Or am I misunderstanding how stream ciphers work?

You are talking about CTR mode, which is CPA secure. Repeating a counter could create (IV,key) - reuse problem that can create a crib-dragging attack. There is no danger in incrementing, it is simple to use, any other choice won't bring any advantage since we assume they are known.

Note that ChaCha20Poly1305 is more than a CTR mode - ChaCha20 has a built-in CTR mode - and with Poly1305, we have authenticated Encryption mode that provides you Confidentiality, integrity, and authentication if properly used.

@kelalaka I'm well aware of the IV,key reuse issue. What I was saying is that any odd number is by definition indivisible by 2, so adding it repeatedly to the counter would be guaranteed to visit every possible value before reusing old ones. But, it would visit those in an unpredictable order and, if chosen right, with a hamming distance between successive counters of several bits changed. My question is, why is this not used to make chosen text attacks even more difficult? Why does it not improve security?

In Kerckhoffs Principles, we assume all know but the key, so your method of IV generation is assumed to be known. So there is no improvement.

@kelalaka I'm well aware of that as well. I chose ChaCha20Poly1305 as my example because there's many, many different usages and implementations of ChaCha to the point its meaningless to just arbitrarily point to "ChaCha." The specific standard ChaCha20Poly1305 does use an increment-by-1 counter in the ChaCha stream cipher, which is why I referenced it.

@kelalaka by the same logic as applying Kerckhoffs Principle to dismiss a pre-agreed counter with pre-agreed increments, we should dismiss a pre-agreed IV altogether as well. So, my point stands and I'm hoping to find a real answer helping elucidate the design considerations as I'm sure they must have considered it but decided not to for concrete reasons

I told you incrementation is easy to use and already has CPA security. What do you need more?

We want simple constructions so that they are easy to analyze. Moreover, you need to send more data than the standard counter mode. How we are going to pre-agree? Why does one have keep this data? What does your construction bring to the table? Nothing!

In short, the unicity of counter values is important for counter-based encryption. The internal functions of such schemes are designed so that distinct counters lead to random and independent outputs. You are free to update the counter as you wish, as long as that prerequisite is fulfilled. From a provable security standpoint, there's no difference.

Trying to clarify the very apt comments:
To a large extent, the strength in stream ciphers resides in the output transformation (call it $f$ which is highly nonlinear with a lot of desirable properties. It has been designed for strength regardless of the update of the input, therefore any counter update which is a permutation of the inputs is sufficient from this point of view. Therefore the CTR update
$$
x \mapsto x+1
$$
is particularly fast and good enough, resulting in consecutive outputs
$f(x)$ followed by $f(x+1)$
instead of doing the counter update
$$
x \mapsto \pi(x)
$$
for some complicated permutation of the counter space which would result in consecutive outputs
$f(x)$ followed by $f(\pi(x)).$
Since the map $\pi$ is public there is no difference in strength between the two approaches other than the fact that $\pi$ is more costly to implement and slows the cipher down.

That makes sense and thank you for this. Two followup: (1.) if we look from an algorithm/software standpoint (which I know disgusts number theoretic enthusiasts, but this is still valid as its equally a big attack vector), ChaCha only muxes bits via xor and add, so the hamming difference between each blocks inherently limits the protection against known text, and infact this is the principle attack methodology for lower ChaCha6; (2.) what if the counter is a private extension of the private key, starting with a private value and incrementing by a private amount each time?

actually under a known text attack you can extract the difference between the successive values $\pi(x)\oplus \pi(x+1)$ so I don't know that there is a significant difference in security

and if the counter is private, seeded by a private quantity, we are moving away from the counter paradigm, so that's an essentially different mode of operation--making CTR public is why that mode is attractive for certain applications
